# Nativescript - Image not resizing

Tags: css, nativescript

So i have this really wierd situation. I have 2 icons, 288x288px both. But the first icon, shows up bigger than the other in the app.

Her is my xml:

```
<GridLayout scaleX="1.0" scaleY="1.0" class="background" rows="auto, auto, auto, auto" columns="*, *">
  <StackLayout colSpan="2">
    <Image class="logo" stretch="none" src="res://logo"></Image>
  </StackLayout>

  <GridLayout colSpan="2" class="login-container" row="1" rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto" columns="*">
    <StackLayout class="input-wrapper" row="0">
      <TextField class="input" hint="Email" [(ngModel)]="email"></TextField>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout class="input-wrapper" row="1">
      <TextField class="input" hint="Password" [(ngModel)]="password"></TextField>
    </StackLayout>

    <Button colSpan="2" class="sign-in" row="3" cssClass="hello" (tap)="doLogin()" text="Sign in"></Button>

    <StackLayout row="4">
      <Label class="bottom-text" text="Forgot your password?"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
  </GridLayout>

  <GridLayout colSpan="2" row="2" rows="100" columns="*, *">
    <Image width="100" height="100" stretce="none" row="0" col="0" src="res://facebook"></Image>
    <Image width="100" height="100" stretch="none" row="0" col="1" src="res://instagram"></Image>
  </GridLayout>

  <StackLayout colSpan="2" row="3">
    <Label class="register" text="Are you new? Create a new account now!"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

The css part:
    .background {
      background-image: url("res://login_bg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }

```
.logo {
  horizontal-align: center;
  margin-top: 130;
}

.login-container {
  padding: 28;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  width: 310;
  border: none;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.input-wrapper {
  padding: 10;
  background-color: #efefef;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

button {
  background-color: #22252b;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 75; 
  width: 340;
  vertical-align: center;
  font-size: 13;
  margin-top: 7;
}

.bottom-text {
  horizontal-align: center;
}

.welcome-message {
  font-size: 20; 
}

.sign-in {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.social-button {
  width: 100; 
  height: 100;
}

.register {
  margin-top: 7px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

[image: how it looks]

And the 2 icons:

[image: instagram]
[image: facebookk]

Anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<Image width="100" height="100" stretch="aspectFill" row="0" col="0" src="res://facebook"></Image>
```

the `stretch="aspectFill"` did it. Thanks to nativescript slack chat!

edit - fixed spelling of stretc to stretch

Comment: What is NativeScripot Slack Chat?

Comment: https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/?redir=%2Fmessages%2Fgeneral%2F

Answer (score 3):

TO resolve this issue make sure you have both images in all provided drawable resource folders (in *app/App_Resources/Android*) and also change the stretch option:

```
<Image width="100" height="100" stretch="aspectFit" row="0" col="0" src="res://facebook"></Image>
<Image width="100" height="100" stretch="aspectFit" row="0" col="1" src="res://instagram"></Image>
```

Now you are images will be centered and with equal sizes.

---

edit: also fixed spelling of `strech`